# $.Callbacks alternative in angular or a way to manage many callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there an alternative in angular of jquery $.Callbacks? I want a simple way to  to manage callback lists in angular. I want to do the following in angular:

```
function Broadcast(){
    var self= this;
    this._statusRecivedCallbacks = $.Callbacks();
    setTimeout(function () {
        self._statusRecivedCallbacks.fire('arg1', 'arg2');
    }, 500);
}

Broadcast.prototype.onStatusRecived = function(callback){
    if($.isFunction(callback)){ 
        this._statusRecivedCallbacks.add(callback);
    }
}

var broadObj = new Broadcast();

//subscribe to this for example in a controller
broadObj.onStatusRecived(function(arg1, arg2){
    alert('the argument 1 is: ' + arg1 + ' and the argumet 2 is: ' + arg2);
});

//subscribe to this for example in a directive
broadObj.onStatusRecived(function(arg1, arg2){
    alert("I'am suscribe too");
});
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/w0hmqbea/6/

If is there not an alternative in angular, is there an alternative in lodash, underscore or any other crosscutting framework? Perhaps i can do something similar with promises, any idea? But I do not want to do `then().then()`, because I will subscribe to the event in different places like for example in a controller an a directive.

I'm looking for an explicit way and easy to follow, to subscribe to an event in different places like $.Callbacks but in angular without jquery dependency.

For example pubsub is not easy to follow when many objects are suscribe to the same event. And I don't know any way/technique to subscribe to the same event in many objects with promises.

Comment: Check [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: @max yes, but do you know any technique with $q to make an object that expose an event like my example. And notify at the same time all objects that where subscribe to the event line in the example 'onStatusRecived'.

Comment: Promises are like `$.Callbacks("once memory")`. If you want that, use Angular-promises, if not then use jQuery for broadcast events. There's nothing wrong with that?

Comment: @bergi sorry I just edited my question. To explain myself better. The idea is to subscribe in an explicit way from many places to the same event. I do not want the typical pub suscribe of jquery is difficult to follow and track. I want a more explicit way.

Comment: @elranu: What do you consider to be the "typical pub subscribe of jquery"? `$.Callbacks` is pretty explicit.

Comment: @Bergi sure I agree. But I'm looking a similar way in Angular without jquery $.Callbacks

Comment: In Angular it's different. If you want pub-sub then use pub-sub. If you want to use promises, you can use promised. The question is not very specific, so it's hard to answer it with Angular solution.

Comment: @Bergi sure I agree. I'm looking for a explicit way like $.Callbacks but in angular without the jquery dependency.

Comment: @dfsq yes, pub sub is not easy to track and is not explicit when many objects are suscribe to the same event. And with promises I don't know how to be notify in may objects in an explicit way. Sure the question is not specific. I'm open to any alternative. Or perhaps I will hhave to create a $.Callbacks in angular and thats it.

Comment: Th thing is that promises and pub-sub are not the same pattern. I wouldn't try to recreate PS with promises, it's not the right tool for this (once resolved, that's it, you can't publish another event). As for recreating $.Callbacks - this is not about Angular either. It's just simple javascript. Check this quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/ac1dwhss/

Comment: @dfsq thanks! I Think I was drowning in a glass of water. I will use your simple example or I will write a simple $.callbacks service in angular.
Put it as answer if u want. I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't have anything specific for PubSub implementation. As Promises are concerned, I don't think this is correct to compare them with what `$q` service can offer, because they sort of serve different purposes. After all, Promises are not really the pattern to replace PubSub and it's definitely not about events and callbacks.

If your purpose is to write more transparent version of PubSub pattern without jQuery then you can do something like this with pure Javascript.

```js
function Broadcast() {
    var self = this;
    this._statusRecivedCallbacks = [];
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.fire('arg1', 'arg2');
    }, 500);
}

Broadcast.prototype.onStatusRecived = function (callback) {
    if (angular.isFunction(callback)) {
        this._statusRecivedCallbacks.push(callback);
    }
}

Broadcast.prototype.fire = function() {
    var args = arguments ;
    this._statusRecivedCallbacks.forEach(function(callback) {
        callback.apply(null, args);
    });
};

var broadObj = new Broadcast();
broadObj.onStatusRecived(function (arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1)
    alert('the argument 1 is: ' + arg1 + ' and the argumet 2 is: ' + arg2);
});

broadObj.onStatusRecived(function (arg1, arg2) {
    alert("I'am suscribe too");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```